# Exchange 2013 export messages from last month

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, pst

I want to backup Exchange messages incrementally each month. I've tried these scripts:

```
$d = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1)
New-MailboxExportRequest -ContentFilter {Received -gt $d} -Mailbox "username" `
                         -name UserInc -filepath \\some\server\share\userinc.pst
```

and

```
$d = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')
New-MailboxExportRequest -ContentFilter {Received -gt $d} -Mailbox "username" `
                         -name UserInc -filepath \\some\server\share\userinc.pst
```

Both scripts back up all messages in the mailbox.

Whereas:

```
New-MailboxExportRequest -ContentFilter {Received -gt '05/01/2016'} -Mailbox "username" `
                         -name UserInc -filepath \\some\server\share\userinc.pst
```

And:

```
$d = '05/01/2016'
New-MailboxExportRequest -ContentFilter {Received -gt $d} -Mailbox "username" `
                         -name UserInc -filepath \\some\server\share\userinc.pst
```

work flawlessly. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a really nasty i18n bug in the Exchange Management Shell. Even though the ContentFilter expects a DD/MM/YYYY date for a UK Exchange installation, it still checks the date against the US format. This means that the date checks only work for the first twelve days of each month.

Answer (score 0):

"ContentFilter" Parameter receives a [String] object, not a DateTime Object like in your example,

feed it with a string value:

```
$d = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')
New-MailboxExportRequest -ContentFilter {Received -gt $d} -Mailbox "username" `
-name UserInc -filepath \\some\server\share\userinc.pst
```

Comment: I get the same result, with or without the ToString. The entire mailbox gets backed up.